# Trying to load posted public key from http://pgp.mit.edu:11371/ after loading it there

Tags: gpg, pgp

So, I run pgp --dry-run --import test.asc on the public key I gave to the site and then I look it up with that key that it gives back and it says not found.

How to do this properly such that I can test that my key can be looked up on that website?

Why is the website called pgp and the tool is called gpg...so confusing.

Comment: gpg is a F/OSS implementation of the commercial pgp standard.

Comment: What is the output of the import command, and how exactly are you looking up the key on the keyserver?

Comment: well, I originally thought just cut and paste the key in.  Turns out you have to add a '0x'...that seems odd....they should have just had a look up by key since that is how I would think most want to look it up and check it....oh well, finally figured it ou.